# Communicate 2 applications on modification using REST web service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I have two applications , in the 1st application i set operations if an operation is set i have to send its data to a REST webservice and launch a method inside the second application. the problem i don't know when the user is going to set an operation inside the 1st operation so i should always send requests to REST to see if operation is set or not.

In the 1st App

```
  @RequestMapping("/add")
public void  setSomething(){
    final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/from";
    Greeting greeting = new Greeting(3,"Send to the other App");
    System.out.println("======================>>"+greeting.getContent());
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate() ;
    Greeting result= restTemplate.postForObject( uri,greeting, Greeting.class);
}
```

in the 2nd App :

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/from", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> createEmployee(@RequestBody Greeting greeting)
{

    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

it's working the greeting is sent to the other app but the problem when i change the greeting to another value the other app always remember the first value so no mdofication is taken

Comment: without the example i think no body will understand what you want. Please put some code, examples etc

Comment: Looks like you need a Queue here. The app1 listens whether app2 is placed some result in the queue.

Comment: i edited the question , the app2 listen when app1 set operation app2 should retrieve data from REst and launch a method doSomething()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"when the user is going to set an operation inside the 1st operation". When this happens a code from your 1st operation is called right? So why don't you just call a Rest endpoint in your second app to trigger the process that you need.

```
Application 1 :

 If(operationSet){
SendRequestToREST(operation)
notifyApp2()// if your app 2 has rest endpoint you can use RestTemplate
}

Application 2 :

 ListenToRest();
if(operationIsSet){
doSomething()
}
```

*Or if your architecture include more than 2 applications. Just tell and we will invent other solution wiht Message Queue AmazonSNS free service. But if it only for comunication between 2 instances- this solution would be enough*

You asked how the first app1 can notify the second app2. You proposed app2 to check app1 if the parameter is set or no. But now with that solution you can just notifyApp2 at the moment you need it.

```
//I am app1
public void  notifyApp2(){
    final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/from";
    Greeting greeting = new Greeting(3,"Send to the other App");
    System.out.println("======================>>"+greeting.getContent());
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate() ;
    Greeting result= restTemplate.postForObject( uri,greeting, Greeting.class);
}


  @RequestMapping(value = "/from", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> createEmployee()
{
    //I am app2 and someone is calling my rest. I am being notified.
    //maybe they notify me to set my operations setOperation=true;
return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
```

}

and now lets suppose the user is workin with app1. When you call your method setOperationInApp1 from app1, you just call notifyApp2() on the next line. and you will have operations set on the both apps